# Several lists in adapter

Tags: kotlin, adapter, android-recyclerview

Well I have a Json with several arrays that I want to show in a recyclerView, I have thought about accessing the modelParent from the adapter, but there is no way.

The Models

```
class DetallesModelParent{

    var golesLocal: ArrayList<DetLocalModel>? = null       //3 items
    var golesVisitante: ArrayList<DetVisiModel>? = null    // 2 items
}
```

Other:

```
class DetLocalModel(
    val idJugador: String,
    val nombre: String,
    val minuto: String )
```

Other

```
class DetVisiModel(
    val idJugador: String,
    val nombre: String,
    val minuto: String
)
```

In the activity everything went to the adapter to show everything from there:

```
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<DetallesModelParent>, response: Response<DetallesModelParent>) {
val golLocal = (response.body()!!)
Rv_DetLocal.adapter = DetLocalAdapter(golLocal!!)
```

And the adapter:

```
class DetLocalAdapter(val det_partido: DetallesModelParent): RecyclerView.Adapter<DetLocalAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var listaLocal = ArrayList(det_partido.golesLocal)
    var listaVisi = ArrayList(det_partido.golesVisitante)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.partido_goles_row, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(layoutInflate)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemDetPart = golesLocal[position]
        val itemDet = golesVisi[position]
        holder.bindItems(itemDet)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listaLocal.size + listaVisi.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bindItems(plantillaModel2: DetallesModelParent){

            itemView.tv_JugadorLocal.text = plantillaModel2.golesLocal!!.get(adapterPosition).nombre
            itemView.tv_JugadorVisi.text = plantillaModel2.golesVisitante!!.get(adapterPosition).nombre

        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalAdapter$ViewHolder.bindItems(DetLocalAdapter.kt:39)
>           at com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DetLocalAdapter.kt:29)
>           at com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DetLocalAdapter.kt:12)

Comment: Do you have 3 items in the array?

Comment: post 1 edited  * local 3 items  *  visitante 2 items

Comment: This call seems to be invalid: `det_partido[position]`. `det_partido is DetallesModelParent == true`, so, you've defined `[]` operator for `DetallesModelParent` somewhere. Could you post it?

Comment: You have 3 `golesLocal` and 2 `golesVisitante`. Do you want to show 3 or 2 items on the list?

Comment: I want to show the two lists in the same recyclerview. * Premises on the right and * visitors on the left

Comment: DetallesModelParent is in adapter first line

Comment: In the only place that is * DetailsModelParent is in the adapter and in * class DetailsModelParent. It is not anywhere else

Comment: @Cililing yes in line 2 and 3 --var listaLocal = ArrayList(det_partido.golesLocal)
    var listaVisi = ArrayList(det_partido.golesVisitante) ARRAYLIST

Comment: So what? I am asking about `det_partido[position]` call. That `det_partido` is your class and `DetallesModelParent ` has no `[]` operator defined.

Comment: @Cililing I've been filling for hours, and I can't do it, I can't finish my app

Comment: This is last time I'am trying.
You have following call: `det_partido[position]`. `det_partido` is type of `DetallesModelParent` which is your completely custom class. So, if your app compiles, there have to be operator `get()` defined somewhere in that class. Could you post it?

Comment: @Cililing post 1 edited the activity Is this what you want?

Comment: It changes a lot.

Comment: Are premises & visitors related? Or 2 completely different lists you just want to scroll together?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so. The problem in your case is your function `onBindViewHolder`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val itemDetPart = golesLocal[position]
    val itemDet = golesVisi[position]
    holder.bindItems(itemDet)
}
```

`getItemCount` with following implementation will return size of both lists. For example, 5. So, there will be following calls:

```
onBindViewHolder(holder, 0) // ok
onBindViewHolder(holder, 1) // ok
onBindViewHolder(holder, 2) // npe, as item visi has only 2 items.
onBindViewHolder(holder, 3)
onBindViewHolder(holder, 4)
```

When position reach 3 NPE will be thrown. Why? Because with your implementation of onBindViewHolder you try just get 3rd element of... both list.

So, you need to tell what element you should bind on **adapter position**

For example:

```
override fun onBindVieHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position < itemDetPart.count()) {
        // bind the first list
        holder.bindItems(golesLocal[position])
        return
    } else {
        // bind the second one, but remember, that param position is an adapter position, so you have to fix it.
        holder.bindItems(golesVisi[position - goesLocal.count()])
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the result I expected, it may not have explained me well, but thanks anyway.
I want the 5 items the 3 premises on the left and the 2 visitors on the right, for that I want 2 lists. I don't want locals and visitors on the same line (said so). So then sort the final list by the minute

Comment: So use two recycler views. It's the simplest approach.

Comment: In that case I can't order them, but thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't merge two lists **golesLocal** & **golesVisitante** in a one hash map list
so the **IndexOutOfBoundsException** will not occurs any more.

Comment: In order to differentiate between locals and visitors

Comment: well they will remain differentiated but hash map make a covariant relationship between them and you can manage them easier(a bit).

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it